# How to use decode with a part of number in sql

Tags: sql, string, oracle, group-by, count

I am working on a homework where I need to select number of employees and their average salary in a country using a decode function on their phone number to determine a country.
Phone number is in a format of 123.465.7890 and I should determine a country based on prefix of the phone number (011.* = USA, etc.)

```
SELECT DECODE (PHONE_NUMBER, 011. , 'USA', 515. , 'Germany', 590. , 'Canada', 603.,'France'),avg(salary), count(*)
FROM zamestnanci
group by phone_number;
```

Any help with how should I input the prefix in a decode function to be able to match the phone numbers to a country?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` here:

```
SELECT
    DECODE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(PHONE_NUMBER, '^[^.]+'),
        '011', 'USA',
        '515', 'Germany',
        '590', 'Canada',
        '603', 'France'),
    AVG(salary),
    COUNT(*)
FROM zamestnanci
GROUP BY
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(PHONE_NUMBER, '^[^.]+');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use substr to extract the relevant part of the phone number:

```
SELECT
    DECODE (
        SUBSTR(PHONE_NUMBER, 1, 3),
        '011', 'USA', 
        '515', 'Germany', 
        '590', 'Canada', 
        '603', 'France'
    ),
    AVG(salary), 
    COUNT(*)
FROM zamestnanci
GROUP BY DECODE (
        SUBSTR(PHONE_NUMBER, 1, 3),
        '011', 'USA', 
        '515', 'Germany', 
        '590', 'Canada', 
        '603', 'France'
    )
```

Comment: Just a note: This would only work assuming that all country codes are always exactly three characters.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: yes. This follows the spec OP provided.

Comment: Yes this solution works as all the country codes are exactly 3 characters